# Custom class validator throws all errors even if only one field is not valid

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation

In Java Spring boot i made class custome validator.
And if even one field fail in Validator i get always both error messages

[
"WRONG_CAR_COLOR",
"WRONG_YEAR_OF_PRODUCTION"
]

```
public class ElectricCarSpecValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ElectricCarSpec, CreateCarCommand> {

private static final Integer minYearOfProduction = 2000;
private static final Integer carColorRed = 10;
private static final Integer electricCarId = 5;

@Override
public boolean isValid(CreateCarCommand command, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
    if (!command.getFuelTypeId().equals(electricCarId)) {
        return true;
    }
    return command.getYearOfProduction() >= minYearOfProduction && !command.getCarColorId().equals(carColorRed);
}
```

Validator:

```
    @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
public ResponseEntity handleMethodArgumentNotValid(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex) {
    List<String> errors = ex.getAllErrors().stream()
            .map(DefaultMessageSourceResolvable::getDefaultMessage)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body(errors);
}
```

Adnotation:

```
@ElectricCarSpec.List({
    @ElectricCarSpec(field = "yearOfProduction", message = "WRONG_YEAR_OF_PRODUCTION"),
    @ElectricCarSpec(field = "carColorId", message = "WRONG_CAR_COLOR")
```

})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that whatever field you specify, you always do the very same validation - checking if **both** fields are valid.

```
return command.getYearOfProduction() >= minYearOfProduction 
     && !command.getCarColorId().equals(carColorRed);
```

In order to take your `field` property into account, you would need to override [initialize(A constraintAnnotation)](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/ConstraintValidator.html#initialize-A-). It's guaranteed by the docs to be called before `isValid`.

> Initializes the validator in preparation for isValid(Object, ConstraintValidatorContext) calls. The constraint annotation for a given constraint declaration is passed.
> This method is guaranteed to be called before any use of this instance for validation.

Something like this:

```
public class TestConstraintValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ElectricCarSpec, CreateCarCommand> {

    private String field;

    @Override
    public void initialize(ElectricCarSpec constraintAnnotation) {
        this.field = constraintAnnotation.field();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(CreateCarCommand value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        if (field.equals("yearOfProduction")) {
            //validate year of production
        }
        if (field.equals("carColorId")) {
            //validate color id
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Having few `if`s for every field you want to validate is fine, but if there are too many fields to check, you may consider writing a strategy pattern to pick correct validation strategy depending on field name.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know class validator run on each validated field separately. I chose to use class validator because with field validator i couldn't get access to other fields. As is seen on top of my topic first i check fuelTypeId and depended of that i proceed to validate others fields. Can i get acces to others in field validator? On my earliers try 'isValid(CreateCarCommand command, ConstraintValidatorContext context)' - command was null

Comment: @Pewu Sorry, it's my bad here, i somehow misread the first condition and didn't realize the connection between all conditions. On the field level you can't get values from other fields (only the one currently validated), so annotation on the class level is the only option.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of implementing `ConstraintValidator`, you should implement `org.springframework.validation.Validator`. It contains a `validate` method in which you can validate multiple fields separately like

```
public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
  CreateCarCommand createCarCommand = (CreateCarCommand) target;
  if (!command.getFuelTypeId().equals(electricCarId)) {
     return;
  }
  if(command.getYearOfProduction() < minYearOfProduction) {
    errors.rejectValue("yearOfProduction", "WRONG_YEAR_OF_PRODUCTION");
  }
  if(!command.getCarColorId().equals(carColorRed)) {
       errors.rejectValue("carColorId", "WRONG_CAR_COLOR");
  }
}
```

In controller class, declare validator like

```
    @Autowired
    //@Qualifier("ElectricCarSpecValidator") //use if multiple implementations
    private Validator electricCarSpecValidator;
```

and in controller method,

```
electricCarSpecValidator.validate(createCarCommand, bindingResult);
if(bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
   //Errors found
   model.addAttribute("org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.createCarCommand", bindingResult);
}
```